# Prove that function is not continuous in $(0, 0)$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, continuity

We have function $f:\mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$,
$$
f(x,y) = 
\begin{cases}
\frac{xy}{x+y},  & \text{if $x+y \neq 0$} \\[2ex]
0, & \text{if $x+y=0$}
\end{cases}
$$
And the problem asks to demonstrate that $f$ is not continuous in $(0,0)$, and to demonstrate that 
it admits derivatives after any direction from $(0, 0)$.

Comment: What have you done so far ? It's not complicate to find a sequence in $\{(x,y)\mid x+y\neq 0\}$ that converge to $0$ and s.t. $f(x_n,y_n)\not\to 0$.

Answer (score 1):

$f (\frac 1 n, -\frac1 {n+1})=-1$ for all $n$ and $f(0,0)=0$.

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite the expression as $$\frac 1{\dfrac1x+\dfrac1y}.$$

Then with

$$\dfrac1y=\frac1a-\dfrac1x$$

$x$ and $y$ tend to zero simultaneously, while the limit is $a$.